# Recommendation for storing and querying DataFactory run log?

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'd like to store and query the OUTPUT and ERROR data generated during a DataFactory run. The data is returned when calling Get-AzDataFactoryV2ActivityRun.

The intention is to use it to monitore possible pipeline execution error, duration, etc in a easy and fast way.

The data ressembles JSON format. What would be nice is to visualize the summary of each execution through some html. Should I store this log into a MongoDB?

Is there an easy and better way to centralize the log info of the multiple execution of different pipelines?

```
ResourceGroupName : Test
DataFactoryName   : DFTest
ActivityRunId     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ActivityName      : If Condition1
PipelineRunId     : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
PipelineName      : Test
Input             : {}
Output            : {}
LinkedServiceName :
ActivityRunStart  : 03/07/2019 11:27:21
ActivityRunEnd    : 03/07/2019 11:27:21
DurationInMs      : 000
Status            : Succeeded
Error             : {errorCode, message, failureType, target}

Activity 'Output' section:
"firstRow": {
  "col1": 1
}
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best way how you can monitor your ADF pipelines.
Have you considered to use Azure Monitor?
Find out more:
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/visualizations